# Plotting a calculus function

Tags: r, plot, gamma-distribution

[image: argmin_b \frac{\Gamma((\nu+1)/2)}{\sqrt{\nu\pi} \Gamma(\nu/2)} \left( 1+ b^2/\nu \right)^{-(nu+1)/2}]

How can I plot this function in R? I am not sure how to express this function.

Comment: this is not trivial. If you want to plot it as a function of nu, you need to (1) define a function that computes the inner values as a function of b and nu; (2) use `optimize()` to compute the argmin; (3) repeat for a series of values of nu. Can you tell us a little bit more of the context of where this problem arose?

Comment: Thank you Ben for your response. This question is trying to figure out if there is an extreama of this data. I thought I'd plot it first which would help me to see, supposed v>0,  step size of 0.2, the initial value of 3.

Comment: The function is a Student's t pdf, R function dt.  But argmin would be + or - Inf.  I don't understand how that's interesting.

Comment: @BrianMontgomery Thank you for pointing the infinity issue out. I was trying to figure out why gradient descent would not be able to find an extrema by plotting it. But I was not aware this is the student t-distribution pdf.